# What is the advantages and disadvantages using UdpClient over Socket

Tags: c#, .net, performance, networking, abstraction

I'm currently using Socket class on both server and client to establish udp connection, right now it is working very well but I saw there was another way of using udp sockets, the UdpClient class. My question is what should I use for 3d multiplayer game? Is it affects performance? etc.....
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UdpClient is wrapper class written on Socket class. It is written specifically to use UDP features of socket. you can access the socket instance of UdpClass with property named Client. Like TcpClient is also written on Socket which is used for TCP communication.

Comment: But there is a difference in performance or something like that?

Comment: no as UdpClient also uses Socket class instance for data transmission and receiving.